# Can I instantiate a new object without using function notation? Why?

Tags: python, class, function

If I make a simple class like this:

```
class Foo:
  i = 1
  j = 2
```

Can I instantiate a new object by simply using Foo on the right-hand side ( as opposed to saying Foo() )? I would guess not, but I just tried the following and it worked:

```
finst = Foo
print finst.i
```

Comment: Also note that you every single class you ever define should inherit from `object` (directly or indirectly) - you don't want to deal with the mess that are old-style classes. (Or switch to Python 3, it fixed this among other things)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works, because `i` is not a property of the object (or instance) but of the class. You are **not** creating a new instance.

Try:

```
class Foo:
  def bar(self):
    print 42

finst = Foo
finst.bar()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   TypeError: unbound method bar() must be called with Foo instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Answer (score 1):

You did not instantiate an object. You just defined a variable in class scope, and accessed it.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `finst` is merely an alias for the class `Foo`, and `i` and `j` are class variables, not instance variables. If you had declared them as instance variables:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 1
        self.j = 2
```

Then your code would cause an error.

To answer your question, no, you must call a constructor to create an instance.

Comment: Those `self.i` and `self.j` references need to go under an instance method (function that `self` is passed into).  Otherwise you'll get an error: `self is not defined`.

Comment: @Trey yeah, I just caught that myself too. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

`Foo` by itself is the class object for `class Foo`:

```
>>> type(Foo)
<type 'classobj'>
>>> type(Foo())
<type 'instance'>
```

Your code:

```
finst = Foo
print finst.i
```

decodes as:

1. bind the name `finst` to the `Foo` class object.
2. print the value of the class' attribute `i`